# Import Tab delimited Text File to Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a tab-delimited text file and want to import it in MS Access using VBA code.

I have created an MS Access form and have used the `DoCmd.TransferText` method:

```
DoCmd.TransferText(TransferType, SpecificationName, TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames, HTMLTableName, CodePage)
```

It works well for CSV File. I'm not sure how to do it in case of tab-delimited text files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?  Did you get an error?

Answer (score 2):

Do a manual import, changing the delimiter to TAB, save the import spec, and then specify that import spec in your TransferText command.

Comment: Thanks David. I mport has been done, the Issue left is how to do error Handling.. means if on Button Click, user selectes a  file (Different text file of diffrent format) then how do it pops a msg and tell usr to select proper file... is there anything to do.. I will be highly thanful for urhelp

Comment: I use Windows API to call the Windows file open dialog: http://mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm . As to error handling, a standard VBA error handler in the OnClick event of your command button should to the job just fine.